# tf-idf vectorizer's use_idf parameter explanation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

What is the use of **use_idf** parameter do in tfidf Vectorizer?
Documentation doesn't give much explantion about it.
can someone explain it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `use_idf` is set to `True` (which is the default), then **inverse document frequency** is taken into account during transformation. What this causes is that tokens that appear in a lot of documents will be automatically deemed less informative than those that appear in fewer documents.

If you set it to `False`, only term-frequency (count of words in a document) is used.

Check this good explanation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf).